# Committee created by 2 different parties (A, B) which consist of men and women

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The given problem is the following:

> A city council is governed by two parties A and B. Party A is
> represented by 12 members of which 3 are women and Faction B is
> represented with 13 members of which 5 are women. Find how many ways
> a committee of eight can be formed in which an equal number of men and
> women participate and an equal number of members from both two
> factions.

**My solution so far**:

Group A has 9 men and 3 women. Group B has 8 men and 5 women.

We can distinguish 4 different cases where the problem's requirements are satisfied:

1. group A: 4 men, group B: 4 women.
2. group A: 3 men, 1 woman, and group B: 1 man, 3 women.
3. group A: 2 men, 2 women, and group B: 2 men, 2 women.
4. group A: 1 man, 3 women, and group B: 3 men, 1 woman.

$$ \binom{9}{4} \binom{3}{0} \binom{5}{4} \binom{8}{0} + \binom{9}{3} \binom{3}{1} \binom{5}{3} \binom{8}{1} + \binom{9}{2} \binom{3}{2} \binom{5}{2} \binom{8}{2} + \binom{9}{1} \binom{3}{3} \binom{5}{1} \binom{8}{3} $$

Is my answer correct ? If not what am I missing here ?

Comment: Are the other 9 members of Party A and the other 8 members of Faction B all men?

Comment: Yes, we can safely suppose that!

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct